# Can't get confirmation from AJAX form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm starting to learn some jQuery, and I'm not very good at it at the moment. But I needed a way to submit a form in my website with no refresh. I found a *popular* example to submit a form with AJAX.

This is my form:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="envio.php" method="post" name="contact-form">

        <label for="message" class="contact-form-label font-open italic small-size" id="lang13">
              Message                        
        </label>
        <textarea class="text-big font-open regular medium-size" name="message"></textarea>

        <input onclick="openSubmitPopup()" type="image" id="arrowsubmit" src="images/icons/Icons_navigation-07.png" name="submit">
</form>
```

And this is the jQuery code:

```
<script language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-form').submit(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'envio.php', //$(this).attr('action')'',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });    
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }); 
})
// ]]></script>
```

This sends the form correctly. However, I don't know how to make a confirmation `<div>` to pop when it sends the form.

Comment: You want to notify user when it sends the form or when the form is submitted successfully?

Comment: do it in your success closure

Comment: Just write the Jquery for the popup right after your Ajax code. Since Ajax calls are by default 'Asynchronous', the code will get executed without waiting for the response of the Ajax. If you want to show the div only after receiving success, then write your code within the 'success' curly braces of your Ajax. For popping the div you can add it in your html, keep it hidden and just do a .show() in your code.

Comment: hey you forgot to prevent the default submit event, oh wait .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success callback function call the method to show pop up

```
<script language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-form').submit(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'envio.php', //$(this).attr('action')'',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
               openSubmitPopup(); //Assume, the function to show pop up works perfectly :)
            }
        });    
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }); 
})
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use confirm() function this is a native javascript code

```
    <script language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contact-form').submit(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'envio.php', //$(this).attr('action')'',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                }
            });    

            var confirmation = confirm('Would you like to submit it?');
            if (confirmation == true) {
                $(this).submit();                
            }
        }); 
    })
    // ]]></script>
```